# How do I swap the last column in a csv file to be the first column? + awk

Tags: bash, awk, sed

How do I swap the last column in a csv file to be the first column?

I am thinking of using awk but not sure?

`awk -F, '{print $1,$2}' filename`

OR is `sed` a better option?

Comment: Is it a two-column CSV file?  If so, what you've got is fine.  If not, then you need to work harder.  Does it work for you?  Do you have any nasties like `"Column 1 contains a comma ',' here","And so, too, does column 2"`?  Again, if so, you have to work a lot harder.

Comment: treat it as an arbitrary length of columns. each columns is inside double quotes `"strings and 9999"`. i'll post a sample.

Comment: Data inside quotes isn't a problem unless the data inside quotes can contain commas, but embedded commas are moderately probable if the data is inside quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For an arbitrary number of columns, you can do:

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=",";} {temp=$NF; $NF = ""; sub(",$", ""); print temp, $0}' filename
```

- `OFS=FS=","` sets the output and input field separators to comma.
- `temp = $NF` saves the original contents of the last column in a variable.
- `$NF = ''` empties the last column in the input.
- `sub(",$", "")` gets rid of the extra comma left by that
- `print temp, $0` prints the saved last column followed by the rest of the input.

If you know how many columns there are, it's probably easier to do this using `cut`. If there are 9 columns, you can do:

```
cut -d, -f9,1-8 infile > outfile
```

Comment: I wonder if it was really 'swap' or did they mean 'rotate' (so the old $NF becomes $1, the old $1 becomes $2, the old $2 becomes $3, ..., the old $(NF-1) becomes $NF).  The question is ambiguous, and the solution in the question is adequate for a 2-column CSV file.

Comment: @Barmar tks, that outputs to the screen a space delimited format, i want a comma delimited? do I have to do ` filename > tmpfile && mv tmpfile filename` to overwrite the existing file?

Comment: I added a `BEGIN` block to set the input and output field separators to comma. And yes, you have to do that to replace the original file, `awk` doesn't have a way to update a file in place.

Comment: Sorry but must be my bad english, that swaps the last and first column, I don't want this. I want to move the last column so it is the 1st column?  sorry

Comment: Updated the answer to do that

Comment: thats a syntax error here `$NF = ''; `  have tried `$NF = $1; ` but this copies the original first column to the end

Comment: ah think this is it `$NF = '';` that should be 2 double quotes before the semicolon, but that leaves a comma at the end of every row, any way to remove this comma?

Comment: Shouldn't the sub be the other way round...`sub(",$", "")` ?

Comment: @JID yes it should but of course `$NF = ""; sub(/,$/,"")` could just be written as `sub(/,[^,]*$/,"")`.

Answer (score 3):

```
sed 's/\(.*\),\([^,]*\)/\2,\1/' YourFile
```

In this case, sed is fully compliant.

An optimization from @JID using the fact that there is no ending `,` and based on behaviour of group order

```
sed 's/\(.*\),\(.*\)/\2,\1/' YourFile
```

Comment: You could just do `/\(.*\),\(.*\)/` as there isn't going to be a comma after the last comma.

Comment: right, the first group take the max available soit works perfectly and *faster*. I adapt the reply

Answer (score 2):

Using gawk and gensub

```
awk '$0=gensub(/(.*),(.*)/,"\\2,\\1","1")'
```

---

#### Input

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

#### Output

```
6,1,2,3,4,5
f,a,b,c,d,e
```

---

If you wanna switch them

```
awk '$0=gensub(/([^,]+),(.*),(.*)/,"\\3,\\2,\\1","1")'
```

#### Input

```
1,2,3,4,5,6
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

#### Output

```
6,2,3,4,5,1
f,b,c,d,e,a
```

---

Same in sed

```
sed -r 's/([^,]+),(.*),(.*)/\3,\2,\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with a proper CSV parser. Ruby comes with one

Do you want to exchange the first and last fields?
Or do you want to move the last field to the front?

If the latter:

```
ruby -rcsv -ne '
  row = CSV.parse_line($_.chomp!)
  row.unshift(row.pop)
  # to exchange first and last fields: row[0],row[-1] = row[-1],row[0]
  puts CSV.generate_line(row)
' <<END
a,b,c
d,e,f
g,h,"""Just drive,"" she said"
END
```

```
c,a,b
f,d,e
"""Just drive,"" she said",g,h
```

(this does not account for fields containing newlines)

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk and some others all you need is:

```
$ echo 'a,b,c' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$0=$NF FS $0; NF--} 1'
c,a,b
```

otherwise this will work with any awk:

```
$ echo 'a,b,c' | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","} {$0=$NF FS $0; sub(/,[^,]*$/,"")} 1'
c,a,b
```